# Overwrite URL on blog posts

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting, blog-page

I would like to overwrite my URL on single blog posts. 
At the moment my posts are displaying as www.mydomain.co.uk/post-title, however I would like them to be as 
www.mydomain.co.uk/blog/post-title so /blog/ always displays before post item, I've tried to do that from permalink level but when I put /blog in Post name box it works, however all my single Custom posts are displaying as /blog/custom-post-item which is not what I'm after as I would only like that to happen for blog posts and not for custom post types.

Any tips.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Custom Post Types the following in your permalink settings should work just fine.

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

### [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eP8UH.jpg)

(Below can still be applicable depending on your use of custom post types)

Keep your regular permalinks on blog like you have it in settings.  And in your custom post type arguments the "with_front" Boolean field will help you achieve what you are looking for.

```
...
'rewrite' => array(
    'with_front' => false,
    'slug' => 'your-slug'
),
...
```

More info about rewrites here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, sorry I wasn't clear enough those are not custom posts but core WP posts types so there is no custom posts type argument in my function.php

Comment: Can you clarify "however all my single Custom posts are displaying as /blog/custom-post-item which is not what I'm after".  What are you referring to as a single custom post.  post_type = post? or something else?

Comment: Yes that is correct post_type=post

Comment: Then my edit above should work properly.